# Google Admin - role privileges relation to specific APIs not found

Tags: roles, privileges, google-admin-sdk

A table for each API with which privilege is required would be VERY useful - I assume one exists but Googling gives no such thing!

In my case I need to know what (minimal) role privilege(s) is/are required for the https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customers/my_customer API (GET) unless I have "Super Admin" turned on I don't have access to this API (403) the I have tried various combinations of the privileges added with "Super Admin" with no success

Regards
Linden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `Super Admin` is necessary in order to call [customers.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/customers/get). Even if [a custom role is created](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2406043) with all possible privileges, 403 is given as long as `Super Admin` role is not set.

#### Request feature:

Regarding a table relating admin privileges and API methods, you could try request it via `Send feedback` at the [Admin SDK documentation page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/get-start/getting-started) or at [Admin roles for businesses](https://support.google.com/a/topic/9832445?hl=en&ref_topic=2785005).

Comment: Thanks for that ,,,. I was just amazed that the get for my_customer (Tenant in other SSOs) requires such a heavy handed permission set - I've implemented Okta, Azure and Oracle SSO and while all have there issues the common thread is poor documentation at the API level (Okta possibly the easiest to use)